# Select JSON values with special characters

Tags: json, string, select, jq, any

I am looking to detect anomalies in my JSON values. 
Here's an example of the data queries via jq

```
"2014-03-26 01:58:00"
"9019549360"
"109092812_20150626"
"134670164"
""
"97695498"
"680561513"
```

I would like to display all the values that contain a `-` or a `_` or is `blank`.

In other words, I'd like to display the following output

```
"2014-03-26 01:58:00"
"109092812_20150626"
""
```

Now, I have tried the following:

```
select (. | contains("-","_"," "))'
```

This appears to work, but in order to make it more robust, I'd like to expand this to include all special characters.

Comment: You could use the [regular expression](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE) filters to find the values of interest...

Comment: Please define all special characters, do you mean anything other than a letter or number?

Comment: That is correct. Everything except A-Z, a-z, 0-9. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query won't detect empty strings, and will possibly emit the same string more than once.  It would be easier to use `test`, e.g.:

```
select( length==0 or test("[-_ ]") )
```

Note also that the preliminary '.' in your query is unnecessary.

### Addendum

From one of the comments, it awould appear that you will want to specify "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" or similar as the argument of `test`.